# DEBUG logs are not printing

Tags: java, log4j, jboss-4.2.x

I am developing a web application, In this I am using Log4j. I am running this application in JBoss-4.2.2GA server. My problem I am trying to display DEBUG logs in console and file but it is **not printing the DEBUG logs.**

This is jboss-log4j.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

  <appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="/Temp_Logs/server.log"/>
      <param name="Append" value="false"/>
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
       <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <category name="org.apache">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>
   <category name="jacorb">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>
  <category name="org.jgroups">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>
   <category name="org.quartz">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>
   <category name="org.jboss.management">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>
   <category name="org.jboss.serial">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>
   <root>
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
   </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

My Java class

```
  public class Test {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName());
    logger.info("This is INFO");
    logger.debug("This is DEBUG");
    }
```

I am getting the following output only...

This is INFO

please help me....

thanks & regards

Comment: Is your Test class in `jgroups` or `jacorb` directory?

Comment: My Test class is from my own package like com.mycompany.test

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your config file:

```
<category name="your.class.package">
  <priority value="DEBUG"/>
</category>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it's not displaying Debug messages. It is displaying only Info messages.